# Is is possible to do sentiment analysis other than just positive, negative and neutral in Python or other programing language

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have searched the internet and there is more or less the same sentiment analysis of a sentence i.e Positive, Negative or Neutral. I want to build a sentiment analyzer that look for the following sentiments/emotions for a sentence.

```
happy , sad , angry , disaapointed , surprised, proud, in love, scared
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice for you to explore a bit further what you tried so far and more in details of what you want to do. So, I'm answering this based on the assumption that you want to work with an emotion-based Sentiment Analysis. Actually there is an area of research that focus on identifying emotion from text.

In many cases, the problem is still treated as a multiclass classification problem, but instead of predicting sentiment polarity (positive, negative or neutral), people try to find emotions. The existing emotions vary in different research and different annotated data, but in general it looks like the ones you mentioned.

Your best chance to understand this area further is to look for papers and existing datasets. I'll list a few here for you and the emotions they work with:

- [An Analysis of Annotated Corpora for Emotion Classification in Text](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C18-1179.pdf). Literature review of methods and corpus for such analysis.
- [Emotion Detection and Analysis on Social Media](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.08458.pdf). Happiness, Sadness, Fear, Anger, Surprise and Disgust
- This [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/sa-emotions/overview) is a good source for training data. Sadness, Enthusiasm, Neutral, Worry, Love, Fun, Hate, Happiness,